# need help on basic java program develpment

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a java program that is similar to a calculator. It's a calculator that will calculate how much weight you have on a lifting bar. I'm very new to java so idk what I'm doing. So when weight lifting if you put two 10 lbs plates on each side, you're adding 20 lbs total. im looking on how to make it so the user types in 10 and the program actually adds 20 to the weight. so how do I do that with multiple values? (2.5=5, 5=10, 10=20, 25=50, 35=70, and 45=90).

please try and keep it simple as I'm new to java and am looking to learn as much as i can.

Comment: post the code you tried and problem you faced

Comment: You multiply the input by 2?? This question is not well researched at all without any examples..

Comment: multiply by 2? `weight += plate * 2;`

Comment: You should follow tutorials if youre new. When you face à problem after having tried, come back and ask a question.

Comment: ok thank you. i just wasnt sure how to go about this. whether to multiply it by 2 or is i needed to set a case a break list.

Answer (score 1):

Try below one

```
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.Map;

 public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Map<String,Double> map= new HashMap<String,Double>(); // create a hash map where key is the weight and the value is double of weight.
     for (String value : args) { // iterate over arguments and compute the weight
             map.put(value,Double.parseDouble(value)*2);
     }
     System.out.println(map);//print the output
 }

}
```

how to compile and execute from command line?

**compile**

```
   javac Test.java
```

**Execute**

```
   java Test 2.5 5 10 25 35 45
```

**output**

```
{2.5=5.0, 10=20.0,45=90.0,5=10.0, 35=70.0, 25=50.0}
```

Comment: throwing in a random code will not really help. Your answer does not explain anything and besides copy and paste will the thread owner not really do more.

Comment: Is it a random code? i understood the question an answered accordingly.

Comment: in my opinion an answer shall explain a solution and help the person to learn. Just putting code as answer does not do any of them... as said my opinion

Comment: I got it. I appreciate for guiding me on right path, Thanks